# event.pageX is working in Chrome but not working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, d3.js, svg

This portion of code is working in chrome but not working in firefox.

I even tried `Window.event.pageX` and `event.pageX` but still it is not working in firefox.

It is just a tooltip over specific points

```
   var points = g.selectAll("path").data(dataset);

    points.enter().append("path");
    points.on("mouseover", function (d) {

                        div.transition()
                                .duration(200)
                                .style("opacity", 1.5);
                        div.html("data")
                                .style("left", (window.event.pageX) + "px")
                                .style("top", (window.event.pageY - 28) + "px");

                        return d;
                    });
```

Comment: Just a tip: opacity goes from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing

```
div.html("data")
                                .style("left", (window.event.pageX) + "px")
                                .style("top", (window.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
```

try

```
div.html("data")
                                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
```

Comment: I tried that too but it is not working , I even tried this.event.pageX and event.pageX . still nothing

Comment: does this example work on your FF http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/a22c42db65eb00d4e369 you will see in the xample too he is using d3.event.pageX and it works on my FF. May be you need to upgrade your FF